# Quickbooks POS Customer not found

Tags: xml, quickbooks

I'm running this code  on QuickBooks Web-Connector to add a SalesOrder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <?qbposxml version="3.0"?>
    <QBPOSXML>
        <QBPOSXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <SalesOrderAddRq requestID="253182747">
                <SalesOrderAdd>
                    <CustomerListID>400001000663</CustomerListID>
                    <SalesOrderType>SalesOrder</SalesOrderType>
                    <SalesOrderItemAdd>
                        <ListID>288</ListID>
                        <Qty>2</Qty>
                    </SalesOrderItemAdd>
                </SalesOrderAdd>
            </SalesOrderAddRq>
        </QBPOSXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBPOSXML>
```

and I already have the customer referenced by its ID in the xml code to the customer list in the Quickbooks POS application, but it keeps returning this error - Customer not found:

```
<QBPOSXML>
    <QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
        <SalesOrderAddRs requestID="253182747" statusCode="20006" statusMessage="Customer 400001000663 not found" statusSeverity="Error">
            <SalesOrderRet/>
        </SalesOrderAddRs>
    </QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
</QBPOSXML>
```

I double checked the references and the Code sample in here:
https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html
but still couldn't figure out why.
I'd really appreciate any help.

Update:
Here is the customer in the customer list showing its ID
[Customer in POS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usVAa.png)

The CustomerID data Type in the SDK documentation is: Unique QBPOS ID value identifying the customer being referenced.

Comment: Can you show us the customer record for that customer, showing its id?  If you want, just show us the id, as read from the saved data, and nothing else.  I just want to make really sure you got that id correct.

Comment: @AgapwIesu done, I updated the question and its in it

Comment: What is the data type for that customer id?

Comment: @AgapwIesu as written in the link in the question: IDTYPE
An IDTYPE (identifier type) is a string with a theoretical maximum length of 36 digits, though the allowed maximum depends on the situation. An IDTYPE returned from QuickBooks is a concatenation of the object ID and creation time, separated by a hyphen.

Comment: So if it is a string type, then the graphic you linked shows that it has an additional digit that you did not include in your code above, a leading zero.  In string types, `400001000663` is different from `0400001000663`.

Answer (score 0):

If Quickbooks uses a string type for the customer id, then the graphic you linked shows that it has an additional digit that you did not include in your code above, a leading zero. In string types, `400001000663` is different from `0400001000663`.

Comment: no i tried both and it didn't work! anyways, I solved it by running a query to retrieve all the customers list and i checked the IDs and i found that the id in the UI is not helpful in running XML queries.

Answer (score 0):

The UI Customer ID is NOT the ListID for the customer.

So, the only way to do it is:

1. do a CustomerQuery first to get the ListID associated with the
   customer.
2. re-run the code above with the real ListID instead of
       the Customer ID found in the application interface.